# É aceitável usar tags <h2>, <h3>, <p>, <div> dentro de links/âncoras (<a></a>)?

Tags: html, seo, html-tags

É aceitável em questão SEO e semântica usar tags como `<h2>`, `<h3>`, `<p>` e `<div>` dentro de `<a href=""></a>`?

Notei que para tornar itens em uma página as pessoas costumam usar uma estrutura semelhante a esta:

```
<div class="item">
    <a href="produto/1">
        <figure>
            <img src="images/produto-1.jpg" alt="produto 1">
        </figure>
        <h2>Produto</h2>
        <p class="price">R$ 1000</p>
    </a>
</div>
```

Eu sei que a tag `<a>` é inline e necessita do `display: block` para que funcione, mas a questão realmente é sobre SEO e semântica.

Comment: No HTML5  a tag `<a>` pode ser inseridas parágrafos inteiros, listas, tabelas,e assim por diante, até mesmo seções inteiras, contanto que não há conteúdo interativo dentro do mesmo, acredito que só iria perder a semântica se houvesse algo do `<a>` que altera-se o seu comportamento natural.

Comment: Guilherme, sei que a sua pergunta é quanto a CEO, mas no HTML5 o conceito de `inline` x `block` sofreu um amadurecimento, agora os elementos estão organizados por categorias, sendo que um elemento pode receber uma classificação diferente dependendo de algumas condições... para entender melhor, leia: [Content categories](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_categories)... no caso do [<a>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a) ele tanto pode ser um `conteúdo de texto` quanto um `conteúdo de fluxo`.

Comment: @TobyMosque só um detalhe CEO != SEO.

Comment: ops, digitei CEO por engano, era SEO mesmo.

Comment: Apenas para incrementar as respostas, deixarei [essa resposta no webmasters](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/20469).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> É aceitável usar tags `<h2>`, `<h3>`, `<p>`, `<div>` dentro de links/âncoras (`<a></a>`)?

Sim. [Isto é um recurso do HTML5](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-a-element). Outras versões não permitiam este uso.

Já o contrário (colocar `<a>` dentro de `<h1>`, `<h2>`, etc.) é o mais utilizado até hoje. Há vários exemplos. um dos mais notáveis, a meu ver, é o de documentações do [GitHub](https://github.com). Passando o mouse por cima de um título, aparece uma imagem de uma âncora contendo o link completo até aquela âncora.

Comment: Sim é o mais usado por ecommerces como o Ebay, no entanto eu digo isto de usar dentro do `<a>` na intenção de tornar tudo clicável. Se bem que acho que vou passar a usar clicável apenas o título e a foto.

Comment: Aí vai do seu objetivo. Eu manteria a abordagem clássica, que funciona pra tudo.

Comment: Não me expressei direito, acho que a abordagem me parece a classica, o que pretendo é fazer algo como (resumido) `<h2><a></a></h2><a><img></a>`... Seria isto o classico não?

Comment: Isso mesmo. É o que usaria.

Comment: Tinha me esquecido de marcar como correta :) Obrigado!

Answer (score 11):

Na especificação da tag [`<a>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a) em **Permitted elements** do HTML5 os seguintes elementos são suportados e por serem suportados são semanticamente corretos se não alterarem o comportamento original do `<a>`:

```
>  <a>, <abbr>, <address>, <article>,
> <aside>, <audio>, <b>,<bdo>, <bdi>, <blockquote>, <br>, <button>,
> <canvas>, <cite>, <code>, <command>, <data>, <datalist>, <del>,
> <details>, <dfn>, <div>, <dl>, <em>, <embed>, <fieldset>, <figure>,
> <footer>, <form>, <h1>, <h2>, <h3>, <h4>, <h5>, <h6>, <header>,
> <hgroup>, <hr>, <i>, <iframe>, <img>, <input>, <ins>, <kbd>, <keygen>,
> <label>, <main>, <map>, <mark>, <math>, <menu>, <meter>, <nav>,
> <noscript>, <object>, <ol>, <output>, <p>, <pre>, <progress>, <q>,
> <ruby>, <s>, <samp>, <script>, <section>, <select>, <small>, <span>,
> <strong>, <sub>, <sup>, <svg>, <table>, <template>, <textarea>,
> <time>, <ul>, <var>, <video>, <wbr>
```

Link Recomendado SOEN: [Is putting a div inside an anchor ever correct?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1827965/is-putting-a-div-inside-an-anchor-ever-correct)

Comment: Acho que ele está dizendo usar as tags dentro de `<a>` e não fora como _parent_ (tag pai/superior) de `<a>`.

Comment: @KaduAmaral, tanto pai quanto filho aceitam os mesmos elementos, da pra ver isto em permitted content: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a

Comment: Hmm correto Gabriel, obrigado por esclarecer. Sugiro então que altere sua resposta para _Permitted content_, e remova os elementos interativos da sua lista, pois não são permitidos na tag `<a>` de acordo com a MDN: _  Transparent, containing either flow content (**excluding interactive content**) or phrasing content._.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta +1