# Button (Botão) dentro de um A (Link)? Isso é uma má prática?

Tags: html

Eu estava utilizando uma biblioteca de `Scaffold` para geração automática de códigos HTML. Era especificamente para gerar formulários em Boostrap 3.

Daí eu notei que os links de ações que estavem sendo gerados estavem assim:

```
<a href="url_da_pagina">
     <button class="btn btn-primary"></button>
</a>
```

Parece que o Scaffold dessa biblioteca estava gerando o código do `Anchor` (O famoso Link) com um `Button` dentro apenas para a formatação do Link ficar igual a do botão.

Mas nem precisa, no bootstrap você pode usar assim:

```
<a href="" class="btn btn-primary">Tipo como se fosse um botão</a>
```

A dúvida que me surgiu é: A biblioteca de geração automática de código fez isso como se fosse "algo normal". É realmente "normal"?

Existe algum problema em usar um `Button` dentro de um `A`, ou vice-versa?

Não sei, mas institivamente (ninguém me falou nada ou nenhum artigo que eu li me ensinou isso), tenho uma pequena impressão de que isso é uma má prática (ou gambiarra).

Fazer isso é válido? Esses validadores de código html da vida aprovaria colocar um botão dentro de um link ?

Comment: **Não**, basta colar seu código [aqui](https://validator.w3.org/) e pedir para validar.

Comment: O que está de errado com a pergunta? Poderia fornecer uma sugestão de melhoria

Comment: **Relacionado:** [É aceitável usar tags <h2>, <h3>, <p>, <div> dentro de links/âncoras (<a></a>)?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/107718/3635)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Essa pergunta já foi respondida no SOen, e foi muito bem respondia. Então eu apenas irei traduzir [esta resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6393863/4843158).

#### Isto não é válido!

Apenas com o fato de funcionar, não significa que algo seja válido.

> Modelo de conteúdo: [transparente](http://w3c.github.io/html/#transparent) (tanto o conteúdo fraseado ou conteúdo de fluxo) , mas não deve haver qualquer [conteúdo interativo descendente](http://w3c.github.io/html/#interactive-content).
> O elemento pode ser envolvida em torno de parágrafos inteiros, listas, tabelas, e assim por diante, até secções inteiras, contanto que não há conteúdo interativo dentro (por exemplo, botões ou outros links).

[Segundo a **W3C**](http://w3c.github.io/html/#the-a-element), a tag a (`<a>`) pode receber qualquer elemento, exceto esses:

- `<a>`
- `<div>`
- `<audio>`
- `<button>`
- `<details>`
- `<embed>`
- `<iframe>`
- `<img>` (Se o atributo `usemap` estiver presente)
- `<input>`
- `<keygen>`
- `<label>`
- `<menu>`
- `<object>`
- `<select>`
- `<textarea>`
- `<video>` (Se o atributo `controls` estiver presente)

---

#### Da série, aconteceu comigo...

Em um código que eu estava desenvolvendo eu tinha um `input` dentro de uma tag `<a>`. Ao utilizar no Chrome e Firefox estava "funcionando" normalmente, mas utilizar o `IE` (que é o melhor validador, rsrs) ele apresentava um efeito diferente do apresentado, no meu caso um `X`, por não encontrar os elementos.
Somente depois de algum tempo, que percebi que aquele comportamento "diferente", se dava pelo fato de eu não estar usando o **HTML** corretamente.

E [como dito pelo @renan](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/128355/button-dentro-de-um-a-link-isso-%C3%A9-uma-m%C3%A1-pr%C3%A1tica/128357#comment267661_128355) nos comentários, basta utilizar um [validador de código](https://validator.w3.org/), que verá o motivo de não ser válido explicado em maiores detalhes.

### Nota

No `HTML5` algumas coisas foram mudadas. Como por exemplo, a tag `a` pode conter a tag `img`. Caso não acredite, em min, use o [validador da W3](https://validator.w3.org/nu/#textarea) com o seguinte exemplo:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Estou testando</title>
</head>
<body>

<a href="form_action.asp">
  <img src="w3html.gif" alt="W3Schools.com" width="100" height="132">
</a>

<p>Click the image, and the click coordinates will be sent to the server as a URL query string.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: tanto img quanto div sempre achei que poderia usar. Vivendo e aprendendo!!!!

Comment: @MarceloDiniz Até pode funcionar, mas não é válido. Isso influência em diversos fatores, inclusive no SEO de seu site.

Comment: @Randrade isso me deu idéia para outra pergunta, o que acha de questiornamos alternativas disso no SOPT?

Comment: Desculpe se não entendi, porém, utilizar link (<a>) em imagem é considerado uma má prática? Mas por que? Muitos sites grandes (inclusive SO) utilizam <a> em <img> e é uma questão de usabilidade além de necessidade ou estou enganado? Desculpe se entendi errado...

Comment: @VictorGomes Em que parte do SO possui isso? O que é feito, geralmente, é colocar a imagem via CSS. O que não é "certo", é colocar a tag `<img>` dentro de uma tag `<a>`.

Comment: Sim sim você está certo, me enganei, cara que triste saber que eu estava fazendo errado durante esse tempo todo, olha só, como disse o @MarceloDiniz "Vivendo e Aprendendo!!!"

Comment: De acordo com os testes que fizemos aqui utilizando o validador do w3c a tag  <img> não pode conter dentro do <a> apenas se tiver o atributo usermap. Fora isso, não é errado.

Comment: @Randrade estou ajudando atualizar a sua resposta, é bom fazer isso, para ninguém ficar com informações erradas na cabeça

Comment: @MiguelBatista Isso é um comportamento do `HTML5`. Adicionei uma nota explicando esse detalhe.