# Como criar uma imagem clicável válida para a W3C?

Tags: html, w3c-validador

De acordo com a resposta dessa [pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/128355/button-dentro-de-um-a-link-isso-%c3%a9-uma-m%c3%a1-pr%c3%a1tica?noredirect=1#comment267661_128355) que fiz aqui, a W3C desencoraja o uso de uma tag `img` dentro de um link (`<a>`);

Porém essa imposição da W3C me soou um pouco polêmico, pois desde que eu programo para a Web tenho feito assim, tenho sido ensinado a fazer assim e vejo muitos programadores fazendo assim.

```
<a href="perfil.html"><img src="usuario.png"></a>
```

Então, se não podemos criar a imagem através da junção "IMG dentro de A", qual é alternativa para poder criar um link clicável?

Javascript não pode ser, certo? Se a W3C critica essa prática, qual então seria a alternativa?

Comment: Bem, eu não concordo @GuilhermeGuini. A W3C, pelo que entendi, trata das expecificações de HTML. Ela não poderia simplesmente sugerir usar Js. Eles tem que dar a solução para isso

Comment: Eu iria fazer a mesma pergunta, até favoritei porque fiquei curioso sobre qual é a forma certa de fazer isso

Comment: Eu praticamente sempre fiz da forma errada, não sei mais de nada kkkk

Comment: Gente, esquenta não. Ninguém está errado, vou melhorar as respostas

Comment: @VictorGomes olha a resposta, realmente não está errado. Parece que houve uma má compreensão sobre o que a resposta quis dizer. Peço desculpas.

Comment: Ótimo, eu estava procurando sobre essa possível "má prática" e não tinha achado nada, que bom saber que continuamos certos haha

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Na verdade, uma pequena correção: Quando fiz a pergunta, entendi mal a resposta que dizia que `IMG` não é aceito dentro de `A`.

Da acordo com o W3C não é recomendado usar `IMG` como filha de um `A` quando a tag `IMG` possui o atributo `usemap`.

Então, na verdade não há problemas em usar a um `Img` dentro de um `A`, é válido pelo W3C validator (fiz os testes aqui).

Só apresenta eros quando usamos [usermap](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_img_usemap.asp)

[Nessa Resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6393827/can-i-nest-a-button-element-inside-an-a-using-html5/6393863#6393863) no SOEN, temos a explicação sobre os elementos que não são aceitos pela w3c dentro de um `<a>`.

O Trecho sobre `img` diz o seguinte:

> `<img>` (if the usemap attribute is present)

Que traduzindo é:

> `<img>` (Se o atributo usemap estiver presente)

Peço desculpas pelo susto que alguns passaram, achando que estava fazendo gambiarra!