# Existe uma maneira de redirecionar para outra página ao clicar em uma div?

Tags: html5, redirecionamento

Tenho uma div:

```
<div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6"> //Essa aqui
       <section class="panel div-border-red">
              <div class="symbol red">
                  <i class="fa fa-eye"></i>
              </div>
              <div class="value">
                  <h1 class="count tkts-total" id="stock_danger"></h1>
                  <p>Falta de estoque</p>
             </div>
       </section>
</div>
```

Gostaria de saber se tem alguma forma de redirecionar para outra página clicando na div *(Sem usar AngularJS)*.

Comment: `<a href="link">` foi feito pra isso.

Comment: @FelipePaetzold uma dica: Nunca marque uma resposta de primeira. Sempre aguarde, dependendo da sua dúvida, um tempo. Não precisa ter pressa de marcar. Quando você marca com pressa, você tira a motivação de alguém querer de dar uma outra resposta. ter vários pontos de vista pode ser uma vantagem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Você pode fazer isso facilmente colocando um link antes de iniciar a `div`.

## [Veja em funcionamento aqui](http://solutionsagencia.com.br/testephp/link.html)

Ficando assim:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<!-- Esta linha acima é somente para importar o `CSS` do Bootstrap -->

<a href="http://google.com.br"><div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6"> //Essa aqui
       <section class="panel div-border-red">
              <div class="symbol red">
                  <i class="fa fa-eye"></i>
              </div>
              <div class="value">
                  <h1 class="count tkts-total" id="stock_danger"></h1>
                  <p>Falta de estoque</p>
             </div>
       </section>
</div></a>
```

Comment: É correto colocar uma div dentro de um link, embora funcione ?

Comment: @MagicHat faz parte das specs, e geralmente qualquer coisa diferente de link ou submit para esta finalidade só faz sentido em situações mais complexas (páginas com informações dinâmicas, etc).

Comment: Mais detalhes nesta pergunta: [É aceitável usar tags <h2>, <h3>, <p>, <div> dentro de links/âncoras (<a></a>)?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/107718/70)

Comment: @Bacco É... na verdade, a versão que trata isso de forma correta é o HTML5, anteriormente dentro de um elemento `<a>` só poderia conter elementos em linha, sendo  `div` um elemento em bloco, dependendo da versão pode estar incorreto.

Comment: @Bacco essa aqui também é legal [Button (Botão) dentro de um A (Link)? Isso é uma má prática?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/128355/button-bot%C3%A3o-dentro-de-um-a-link-isso-%C3%A9-uma-m%C3%A1-pr%C3%A1tica)

Comment: @MagicHat html 4 is killed :p

Answer (score 1):

Defina um `id` para `div` e use a função `click`

```
$('#idDiv').click(function() { 
 document.location = 'http://suaurl.com/';
} );
```

Comment: Funcionou, aceitarei a resposta assim que o sistema permitir.

Comment: Eu entendo que essa resposta responde o que foi perguntado, e tecnicamente é correta. Mas que é uma gambiarra danada usar JS pra fazer o que o HTML tem nativo é. Infelizmente eu vejo bastante gente usando isso, o que é um indicador preocupante em termos de qualidade do mercado.

Comment: Neste caso, só criticar a minha resposta não ajuda o AP, então, ajude ele postando a sua resposta também. Assim ele terá outra opção e os demais que forem ler esta pergunta.

Comment: @JcSaint não critico sua resposta, é correta. Critico o autor querer fazer isso, o que foi endossado pela aceitação. Sua resposta está correta, para o que foi perguntado, como já disse antes. Quanto a responder, já postei como comentário na pergunta, e o Wendell já deu a solução. Apesar de além de tudo a sua resposta usar jQuery, que tb não está na pergunta, não acho que tenha nada de errado nela (se tivesse, o pessoal negativaria).

Comment: A outra resposta ter ganhado 4 pontos a mais do que essa mostra por si só qual seria a melhor maneira de resolver o problema. Dar a solução procurada é importante, mas todo mundo pode ir além. Depender do jQuery para fazer essa operação é um absurdo.