# Botão de link não é clicável

Tags: css, html5

O problema é que não possível clicar no botão nem no ícone, como resolvo isso?

Código:

```css
.heroimg{
 position: relative;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-image: url('../img/fjords.png');
 background-size: cover;
 background-position: center;
 height: 100%;
 z-index: -1;
}
.herotxt{
 text-align: center;
 position: absolute;
 top: 50%;
 left: 50%;
 transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="heroimg">
   <div class="herotxt">
    <h1>Informática</h1>
    <a href="#btn">
     <button id="circle">
      <i class="fa fa-chevron-down fa-3x"></i>
     </button>
    </a>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Pode criar um [exemplo verificável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) para entendermos melhor o problema?

Comment: Acredito piamente que está sintaxe de HTML é inválida! `<a><button></button></a>`

Comment: então qual seria a correta?

Comment: Somente `<a>` ou `<button>`, você estiliza o elemento de acordo com sua necessidade e  o evento no caso de `<a>` você omite e emula o funcionamento do `<button>`

Comment: Nelson realmente se vc arrumar a sintax vai ver que a alteração do  z-index nem seria necessária. A outra resposta seria a mais correta

Comment: ambas respostas estão corretas, acabei de ajeitar a sintaxe aqui no meu código

Comment: Ok Nelso agora não há mais problema, editei a pergunta com mais detalhes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nelson se vc corrigir a sintax deixando apenas a tag `<a>` ou usando apenas a tag `<button>` o elemento fica clicável, pois da forma que vc escreveu o HTML a sintax está inválida. Conforme comentado pelo @hunterxhunter e @MarceloBoni

Leia mais sobre isso nessa resposta para ver o que a tag `<a>` aceita dentro dela [É aceitável usar tags <h2>, <h3>, <p>, <div> dentro de links/âncoras (<a></a>)?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/107718/%C3%89-aceit%C3%A1vel-usar-tags-h2-h3-p-div-dentro-de-links-%C3%A2ncoras-a-a)

O correto seria algo como

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  z-index: -22;
}

.heroimg {
  position: relative;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-image: url(https://unsplash.it/100/100);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  height: 100%;
  /* z-index: -1; */
}

.herotxt {
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
#circle {
align-items: flex-start;
text-align: center;
cursor: default;
background-color: buttonface;
box-sizing: border-box;
padding: 2px 6px 3px;
border-width: 2px;
border-style: outset;
border-color: buttonface;
border-image: initial;
text-rendering: auto;
letter-spacing: normal;
word-spacing: normal;
text-transform: none;
text-indent: 0px;
text-shadow: none;
display: inline-block;
margin: 0em;
font: 400 13.3333px Arial;
}
```

```html
  <div class="heroimg">
    <div class="herotxt">
      <h1>Informática</h1>
      <a href="#btn" id="circle">
          <i class="fa fa-chevron-down fa-3x"></i>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
```

---

Vc pode fazer uma gambiarra pegando a classe `.heroimg` e tirar o `z-index: -1` que assim o elemento vai ficar clicável.

Repare que ao remover isso ele fica novamente clicável.

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.heroimg {
  position: relative;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-image: url(https://unsplash.it/100/100);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  height: 100%;
  /* z-index: -1; */
}

.herotxt {
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"


<div class="heroimg">
  <div class="herotxt">
    <h1>Informática</h1>
    <a href="#btn">
      <button id="circle">
        <i class="fa fa-chevron-down fa-3x"></i>
      </button>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Aqui tem um guia da Mozilla sobre `z-index` que pode te ajudar. https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Understanding_z_index

Comment: É verdade, já tentei remover a resposta depois que fiz o teste, porem como ela está aceita não consigo :(

Comment: @MarceloBoni já comentei na pergunta pra ver se ele muda para a outra resposta

Comment: @MarceloBoni resposta corrigida e atualizada

Answer (score 5):

Sua sintaxe como comentada está incorreta. Voce colocou o `button` dentro do `<a>`, que pode resultar em erros.

Você pode setar um `button` como uma `class`, dai faz sentido deixar dentro de um `<a>` como você tentou fazer. Veja:

```
<a href="http://google.com" class="button">Vá para o Google</a>
```

- [Como adicionar href em buttons](https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-add-a-link-to-button-in-HTML)
- [Como criar um botão HTML que atue como um link?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2906582/how-to-create-an-html-button-that-acts-like-a-link)

Comment: Obrigado pelos links